# How to install packages without internet connection

Tags: installation, 10.10, package-management, offline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

I'm just beginner to linux operating system
I have following doubts

1.Now i am using ubuntu 10.10 version
  i dont have net connection in my home
  So how can i install packages manually
  for ex: if me and my friend have same version and same hardware config

if he installed installed all packages in his laptop
can i install all his packages by copy packages from his lap to mine ??
  if there is a way then how to do it??

Thx guys in advance..... :)

Comment: First and foremost, you both need to have the same Ubuntu version (by the way, you should  upgrade to 12.04, 10.10 is not supported anymore), else his packages will cause you missing dependencies, but yes he can download them for you and you can just install them later.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the debs you need off his system out of /var/cache/apt/archives, but you'd need to be sure that you get all the dependencies for the debs you want.  Then you'd install with **dpkg -i**. I'd say it's fairly likely that you may miss a package or two and end up with uninstallable packages, so if you're not sure what you're doing, I'd suggest not doing this.

One alternative, you could also use gdebi to install the debs once you copy them. gdebi will figure out what dependencies you need, dpkg will not until it tries the install, and apt can't install local files.  gdebi is not installed by default, so you'd need to download it first.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have the same packages as you friend do with same version of preparing system .

first you need to grab them from the location mentioned in previous answer . then place the packages in the same location in your pc .

then you can do the thing in two ways .

1. sudo aptitude upgrade
2. cd to the directory where you placed the packages and do like

sudo dpkg -i *.deb .

it will install all the packages . hope that helps .